# Terraform iterate through values

Tags: azure, terraform

Newbie question: Is there any way to loop the variable to storing in mentioned code?. below is my configurations variable.

```
config= [{  
"name" = shared_preload_libraries,
"values" = ["EXAMPLE1", "EXAMPLE2"]
},
{
"name" = "azure.extensions"
"values" = ["EXAMPLE1", "EXAMPLE2", "EXAMPLE3"]
}]
```

I need to iterate in such a way that, for each name in variable the corresponding values should inserterd one by one in below code.

```
 resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "example" {
  name      = name
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example.id
  value     = values 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your `config` as follows:

```
locals {
  flat_config = merge([
      for single_config in var.config: {
        for value in single_config.values: 
          "${single_config.name}-${value}" => {
              "name" = single_config.name
              "value" = value
          }
      }
    ]...) # do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then

```
 resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "example" {
  for_each  = local.flat_config
  name      = each.value.name
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example.id
  value     = each.value.value
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. It worked after some changes like 
name      = each.value.name
value     = each.value.value

one more doubt. Is there any way to implement without using a local variable.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I am having one more doubt, currently I am having two azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server resources. azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example[0] and azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example[1]. Could you please let me know if there is a possibility to include some alternative options like count?

Comment: @iluv_dev I would suggest making new question for that.

Comment: Sure :) i will post a separate question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72471241/how-to-use-terraform-for-each-resource-block-and-count-resource-block created another question. Thank you @Marcin